# At what point can you travel between base camps?

Tags: shadow-of-the-tomb-raider

I'm currently in the Peruvian Jungle trying to get to the village after the plan crashed. My play style involves trying to get everything done and then moving to the next area so I try and collect and do everything possible. Of course with games like this you can't always do everything, for example, I couldn't do the first tomb where the first base camp is because I didn't have the climbing axes.

I'm not sure if you can run back, I haven't tried and it's so far away I don't really want to but because of the jaguar encounter I doubt you can go back on foot anyway. So that leaves travelling between the base camps as the only option.

**At what point in the game is travelling between base camps unlocked?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that this is unlocked after you fight the second jaguar and play as young Lara. You then go back to the area where you have to retrieve your supplies initially in the Peruvian Jungle. From there you can fast travel.

This is before you make it to the village you are trying to get too.

Comment: Also, fast travel to any known base camp is available for most of the game.  There's only a few times where you're at a base camp but fast travel is "not available".